# FreeIPA on Azure setup

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, azure-networking, freeipa

I am trying to setup FreeIPA on Azure as 1 Server ---> 2 Clients without actually utilizing a domain name i.e. I want to use a fictitious domain name such as "example.azure.local" and still have the connectivity between the server and the clients. However, I do want to expose the FreeIPA web-interface to the Server's public IP address for me to easily manage the users.

Is this possible without actually using a domain name? If so, how should I configure my DNS to achieve the same result.

Please Note: I am **not** that comfortable with setting up BIND or any other DNS service, extra information may be required in the DNS department of this setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run a DNS server inside your virtual network, then you have two options:

1. Configure all the clients to connect to the server by IP address (the internal IP of the server)
2. Edit the host files on the client machines to add a DNS entry of your choice mapping to the IP of the server. This can be whatever you want, but will only be resolvable on the machines where you edit the host file.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I ended up setting a DNS using DNSMasq on one of the server in internal network.